# Разница между «<>» и «!=» в Python

Tags: python

Чем они отличаются или же они идентичны? Если различные, то приведите примеры, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос не так прост как может показаться на первый взгляд.

В `Python 2.x` эти операторы являются синонимами,но интерпретатор генерирует слегка отличающийся код:

```
In [2]: import dis

In [3]: dis.dis("1 != 2")
          0 <49>
          1 SLICE+2
          2 SLICE+3          #  <-----
          3 DELETE_SUBSCR    #  <-----
          4 SLICE+2
          5 DELETE_SLICE+0

In [4]: dis.dis("1 <> 2")
          0 <49>
          1 SLICE+2
          2 STORE_SUBSCR     #  <-----
          3 BINARY_LSHIFT    #  <-----
          4 SLICE+2
          5 DELETE_SLICE+0
```

В `Python 3.x` оператор `<>` не определен:

```
In [39]: 1 <> 1
  File "<ipython-input-39-c52e0c69590a>", line 1
    1 <> 1
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

но если очень хочется то можно это ограничение обойти:

```
In [40]: from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL

In [41]: 1 <> 1
Out[41]: False
```

Comment: Лойс, не знал про <>